# Is it possible to create a torrent where nobody has a full copy?

Tags: bittorrent

I'm working with a few other people on different chunks of the same dataset. It would be good to have an easy way of unifying and deduplicating our results. It occurred to me that torrents are already built for the situation where lots of people have different chunks of a file or collection of files, so I thought that might be of use. Is there a way to create a torrent that initially has no seeders, where everyone has some possibly-overlapping subset of the data but nobody has all of it?

Comment: Seems like you want to use a shared cloud drive more than a torrent. All a torrent is is a way to get small pieces of  the same established data from multiple sources. Changing that data would invalidate the torrent.

Comment: Look at Google Sheets.